# Drastic decrease in peers

Tags: bitcoind, peers, p2p

Been running a standalone node on the same hardware for some years now. I run this node simply as a supportive node, unlocked bandwidth to facilitate people bootstrapping the blockchain. No settings have changed recently. I noticed in the last week or so that peer count has dropped drastically, from 200+ to less than 40. Peer count used to fluctuate 190-250, now it fluctuates 39-55ish.

- A reboot of the router and modem did not change peer count
  significantly.
- I deleted and re-assigned the port-forwarding rule to rule out some
  firewall malfunction.
- Verified the port is open using a scanner from the internet
- Reloaded UFW on the node just to be sure
- using `bitcoin-cli netinfo 4` I'm able to verify there are    30+
  incoming connections spread over onion and IPv4
- Speedtest on my internet connection is otherwise normal
- Server disk/memory/CPU usage all well less than 50%

My current bitcoin.conf includes:

```
maxconnections=256
maxuploadtarget=1000000
server=1
daemon=1
bind=0.0.0.0
onlynet=ipv4
discover=1
```

My questions:

- has anyone else noticed a decrease in connections?
- Is it possible my ISP is somehow throttling bitcoind p2p connections?

I understand that it doesn't really matter how many nodes I'm connected to, but when there's a sudden, drastic change not due to some configuration change on my part, I start to wonder what's going on and if there is some attack or issue with the p2p network.

Comment: I have not noticed a decrease in peers on my node. Is it possible that your IP address has recently changed and it hasn't fully propagated through the network yet?

Comment: My IP address is essentially static and has been stable for a period of many weeks